# virtualenvwrapper: how to change mkvirtualenv's default Python version/path to install

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I had this in my `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
```

And I thought that if I just change it to this:

```
PATH="/Users/myusername/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then `virtualenvwrapper` should simply use this as the new "source" Python to use. But that breaks it and issues a warning about the Python version not having any "virtualenvwrapper hooks".

How can I change the *version* `mkvirtualenv` installs by default? I'm looking for this to be a one-time change. I'm aware of the `-p` flag but don't want to have to specify it every time I create a virutalenv.

Comment: Strongly recommend you to use `pipenv` instead of `mkvirtualenv`

Comment: @WaketZheng - I'm aware of `pipenv` but still would like a relevant answer, if only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the code in my question works, I just needed to install `virtualenvwrapper` **for that specific python env**.

For simplicity, I'm now prepending this python version to my path as below, so I can easily change the path in the future:

```
export PYTHON_PATH_LATEST="/Users/myusername/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin"
PATH="${PYTHON_PATH_LATEST}:${PATH}"
```

As an added bonus, this is now also the python version `pipenv` will choose by default.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
alias vv="virtualenvwrapper -p python3.7"
```

Solution 2:

set python3.7 as your default version, for example:

```
export py_which=`which python`
sudo rm $py_which
sudo ln -s `which python3.7` $py_which
```

Comment: This is not a one-time solution. Thanks for your effort.